# Is there a way to avoid "Property 'foo' does not exist on type" and return undefined instead?

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this:

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: string
  baz: number
}
```

I would like to ensure that either both members are present, or neither is. I've tried `type X = Foo | {}`, but this has the issue that it shows the error `property 'bar' does not exist on type X` when trying to access the property (in reality, the access returns `undefined`). I've found that this type expresses what I actually want:

```js
type X = Foo | { [k in keyof Foo]?: undefined }
```

But there's a bit of a lot going on here, and it would be even more complicated if I wanted a union of more types. Is there a more concise way to do an object access without triggering the `property 'bar' does not exist on type X` without using a type guard or casting to `any`?

## Attempt with `never`

In the comments, there is a suggestion using `Record<keyof Foo, never>`, but this does not work as expected. The second suggestion `Partial<Record<keyof Foo, never>>` does work for the original example.

```js
interface Foo {
  a: number
}

type X = Foo | Record<keyof Foo, never>

const x: X = {} // Error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'X'.
console.log(x.a)

type Y = Foo | Partial<Record<keyof Foo, never>>

const y: Y = {}
console.log(y.a)
```

## Example with more types

I'd originally asked about how to use this with more types, here is an example:

```js
interface X {
  a: string
  b: string
}

interface Y {
  c: string
  d: string
}

type Z = X | Y | Partial<Record<keyof (X & Y), never>>

// These work, bu should not.
const z: Z = {a: "x", b: "x", c: "x"}
const z: Z = {a: "x", b: "x", c: "x", d: "x"}
```

Actually, the fact that the last lines work seems to be the case with `X | Y`, nothing to do with the record. It also continues to happen if I use `type` instead of `interface`. So this is probably as good as it's possible to get?

Comment: `Foo | Record<keyof Foo, never>`

Comment: `Foo | {[K in keyof Foo]?: never}` is pretty concise for the constraint you're trying to express; you can always give it a utility name like `type AllOrNone<T extends object> = Required<T> | Partial<Record<keyof T, never>>` but if you're worried about scalability with "a union of more types" you should probably [edit] to show it with a [mre] so that we can address it without having to guess what that looks like.

Comment: @jcalz I've added an example of what I meant with more types. It seems to be a little more flexible in terms of what it accepts than I'd hoped, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do better.

Comment: You're probably looking for [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wR0dYm) then, where the `AllOrNone<T>` applies to each member of your union separately and you intersect them together.  If that suffices I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, that approach looks almost exactly like what I was after, except line 19 should also be an error.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify use cases you care about; line 19 being an error isn't implied by the text of the question (well, I don't see it there).  Anyway does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDdzRN) work for you or am I still missing something?

Comment: I've edited the question, but yes, that is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have a simple way to prohibit excess properties in object types; object types are open and extendible on purpose, and there's no easy `Exact<T>` utility type that closes or seals them.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for the relevant feature request for `Exact<T>` and the various issues surrounding it, workarounds, etc.)

If `Exact<T>` existed, then you'd probably want to turn `Foo` into `Exact<Foo> | Exact<{}>`: it would be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of either `Foo`-with-no-excess-properties or an empty object.  And you'd want to turn the union `X | Y` into `Exact<X> | Exact<Y> | Exact<{}>`.  That would prevent any extra properties from appearing anywhere.  But `Exact<T>` doesn't exist so we can't use it.

---

The closest you can get to prohibiting excess properties is to explicitly enumerate the keys you'd like to prohibit, and then make those keys have [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

To enumerate all the keys in some type, including from different union members, we can write an `AllKeys<T>` utility type:

```
type AllKeys<T> =
  T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
```

That's a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which splits `T` into union members, grabs the keys of each member, and unions them back together.

Then, assuming we have a union `T` and some enumerated list of keys `K` we care about, we can `Exclusify<T, K>` to be another union where we augment each member of `T` to explicitly prohibit excess properties from `K`.  It looks like this:

```
type Exclusify<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T extends unknown ? (T & { [P in Exclude<K, keyof T>]?: never }) : never;
```

That's another distributive conditional type, where we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the each union member `T` with `{[P in Exclude<K, keyof T>]?: never}`, a type with all the keys from `K` not present in `keyof T` (using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)).

And finally we can write `ExclusifyOrNone<T>`, which takes a possibly-union type `T`, "exclusifies" it against all the keys of all the members of `T`, and also allows an empty object by "exclusifying" the empty object type `{}` against those keys also.  Like this:

```
type ExclusifyOrNone<T> =
  Exclusify<T, AllKeys<T>> |
  Exclusify<{}, AllKeys<T>>
```

This could probably be written `Exclusify<T | {}, AllKeys<T>>`, but I'm a bit wary about `T | {}` since such a type *could* be collapsed to just `T` (if `T extends {}`) and I don't want that to happen before the exclusification occurs.  By separating that into two pieces I'm sure that won't happen.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
interface Foo { bar: string; baz: number; }    
type FooOrNone = ExclusifyOrNone<Foo>;
/* type FooOrNone = 
  (Foo & {}) | 
  { bar?: undefined; baz?: undefined; } 
*/

let f: FooOrNone;
f = { bar: "", baz: 1 }; // okay
f = {}; // okay
f = { bar: "" }; // error
```

Looks good for `Foo`; what about `X | Y`:

```
interface X { a: string; b: string }
interface Y { c: string; d: string }

type Z = ExclusifyOrNone<X | Y>
/* type Z = 
  (X & { c?: undefined; d?: undefined; }) | 
  (Y & { a?: undefined; b?: undefined; }) | 
  { a?: undefined; b?: undefined;
    c?: undefined; d?: undefined; } */

let z: Z;
z = {}; // okay;
z = { a: "", b: "" }; // okay
z = { c: "", d: "" }; // okay

z = { a: "", b: "", c: "", d: "" }; // error
z = { a: "" }; // error
z = { a: "", b: "", c: "" } // error
```

Also looks good. The type rejects keys from other union members, while still allowing the empty object.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLwBQUUmUEAHsBAHYAmqUArtQNbUD2A7tVAPxQsU7AGYkoALijUIANwgAnANwECoSFACi5AMZxGqAJbCQWADRREZSjXpQACvPaR5oZCFyFipClToNmbFw8-AAUpABkUADeUADadlAGPFq6jLQQ6IjmgiAiJNgAuryS0nLyUAC+AJQSUrIKyqrg0Cl6hsYA8vIAcuzSWB5EmjptRiaY5vBIKBg4uAA+Q636Y+hRFZMIbrPY2CpJVPLCAIba0ABi7OzRQwBGx-KSqMDySQDmd8cAXiWMALa3BQECoqNQXK5dXrSfDDVLtECQvoZS7sbDKAD0ACooGCoCjEdC8FAhiEUVBIusavNicQYvd5MUmHQIMIkhBaIooPcvozmOlWdIOZViZj0So4BBgFBhJJ8T0kcpRES6Q9JAAiNXmbmSACMlU56PRUHYLGOIAISuiFQNRpNZotMJVjygGv1UENZHkjnk+2ohxOZygAA0bsRjk8Xu87hHXtQPiCCAcFAHoABNUNQbQxqPEWjZuPA0HNKAALRhy3hBIyIepqb2WJxxbLRJJIYpmd5zIF7M5tE7-LZQuqUGpJPT7eO-ZZg85tyn3aHVJp0Sgk8kfOngtn85nQ2I2h3W6gffXXZnwtF4slUB+peUX0d1vdttNIHvjtX6s1XK-bo9dvNB9lUzL9zDzF01T-F97QIICV3DCCtVAkDEOPX8nw9BRvVgj8ENdDCjSw9gfTgmI8O-W5kKzCDhUwr1iKAA)